# 2nd page of TOC overlapping with header

Tags: table-of-contents, header-footer

I am using R's Brew package to automate LaTeX reports, and I am having trouble formatting table of contents so that they don't overlap the header.

The header works correctly, but I have a long Table of Contents and on the second page of the ToC the list begins at the very top of the page on top of the header.
How do I protect my header for multipage ToCs?

Thanks

edit: here is a my code:

```
\documentclass[oneside]{article}
\headsep=30pt
\usepackage[margin=2cm,nohead]{geometry}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks=true,
  pdfauthor={Carl}
}

\graphicspath{{./graphs/}}

\title{Data Dictionary}
\author{Carl}
\date{\today}
\raggedbottom
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{R data}
\lhead{Carl}
\rfoot{Page \thepage}
\begin{document}

\maketitle

\tableofcontents



    \pagebreak


\section{\uppercase{mpg}}

Here is where the labels and other information will go: \\


  % latex table generated in R 3.2.1 by xtable 1.7-4 package
% Tue Aug 04 10:30:04 2015
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rlrr}
  \hline
 & Values & Frequencies & Percent \\ 
  \hline
1 & 10.4 &   2 & 0.06 \\ 
  2 & 13.3 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  3 & 14.3 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  4 & 14.7 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  5 & 15 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  6 & 15.2 &   2 & 0.06 \\ 
  7 & 15.5 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  8 & 15.8 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  9 & 16.4 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  10 & 17.3 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  11 & 17.8 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  12 & 18.1 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  13 & 18.7 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  14 & 19.2 &   2 & 0.06 \\ 
  15 & 19.7 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  16 & 21 &   2 & 0.06 \\ 
  17 & 21.4 &   2 & 0.06 \\ 
  18 & 21.5 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  19 & 22.8 &   2 & 0.06 \\ 
  20 & 24.4 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  21 & 26 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  22 & 27.3 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  23 & 30.4 &   2 & 0.06 \\ 
  24 & 32.4 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  25 & 33.9 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{mpg} 
\label{mpg}
\end{table}


  \clearpage
  \pagebreak


\section{\uppercase{cyl}}

Here is where the labels and other information will go: \\


  % latex table generated in R 3.2.1 by xtable 1.7-4 package
% Tue Aug 04 10:30:04 2015
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rlrr}
  \hline
 & Values & Frequencies & Percent \\ 
  \hline
1 & 4 &  11 & 0.34 \\ 
  2 & 6 &   7 & 0.22 \\ 
  3 & 8 &  14 & 0.44 \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{cyl} 
\label{cyl}
\end{table}


  \clearpage
  \pagebreak


\section{\uppercase{disp}}

Here is where the labels and other information will go: \\


  % latex table generated in R 3.2.1 by xtable 1.7-4 package
% Tue Aug 04 10:30:04 2015
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rlrr}
  \hline
 & Values & Frequencies & Percent \\ 
  \hline
1 & 71.1 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  2 & 75.7 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  3 & 78.7 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  4 & 79 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  5 & 95.1 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  6 & 108 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  7 & 120.1 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  8 & 120.3 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  9 & 121 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  10 & 140.8 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  11 & 145 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  12 & 146.7 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  13 & 160 &   2 & 0.06 \\ 
  14 & 167.6 &   2 & 0.06 \\ 
  15 & 225 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  16 & 258 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  17 & 275.8 &   3 & 0.09 \\ 
  18 & 301 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  19 & 304 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  20 & 318 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  21 & 350 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  22 & 351 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  23 & 360 &   2 & 0.06 \\ 
  24 & 400 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  25 & 440 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  26 & 460 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  27 & 472 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{disp} 
\label{disp}
\end{table}


  \clearpage
  \pagebreak


\section{\uppercase{hp}}

Here is where the labels and other information will go: \\


  % latex table generated in R 3.2.1 by xtable 1.7-4 package
% Tue Aug 04 10:30:04 2015
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rlrr}
  \hline
 & Values & Frequencies & Percent \\ 
  \hline
1 & 52 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  2 & 62 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  3 & 65 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  4 & 66 &   2 & 0.06 \\ 
  5 & 91 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  6 & 93 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  7 & 95 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  8 & 97 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  9 & 105 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  10 & 109 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  11 & 110 &   3 & 0.09 \\ 
  12 & 113 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  13 & 123 &   2 & 0.06 \\ 
  14 & 150 &   2 & 0.06 \\ 
  15 & 175 &   3 & 0.09 \\ 
  16 & 180 &   3 & 0.09 \\ 
  17 & 205 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  18 & 215 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  19 & 230 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  20 & 245 &   2 & 0.06 \\ 
  21 & 264 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  22 & 335 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{hp} 
\label{hp}
\end{table}


  \clearpage
  \pagebreak


\section{\uppercase{drat}}

Here is where the labels and other information will go: \\


  % latex table generated in R 3.2.1 by xtable 1.7-4 package
% Tue Aug 04 10:30:04 2015
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rlrr}
  \hline
 & Values & Frequencies & Percent \\ 
  \hline
1 & 2.76 &   2 & 0.06 \\ 
  2 & 2.93 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  3 & 3 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  4 & 3.07 &   3 & 0.09 \\ 
  5 & 3.08 &   2 & 0.06 \\ 
  6 & 3.15 &   2 & 0.06 \\ 
  7 & 3.21 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  8 & 3.23 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  9 & 3.54 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  10 & 3.62 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  11 & 3.69 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  12 & 3.7 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  13 & 3.73 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  14 & 3.77 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  15 & 3.85 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  16 & 3.9 &   2 & 0.06 \\ 
  17 & 3.92 &   3 & 0.09 \\ 
  18 & 4.08 &   2 & 0.06 \\ 
  19 & 4.11 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  20 & 4.22 &   2 & 0.06 \\ 
  21 & 4.43 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  22 & 4.93 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{drat} 
\label{drat}
\end{table}


  \clearpage
  \pagebreak


\section{\uppercase{wt}}

Here is where the labels and other information will go: \\


  % latex table generated in R 3.2.1 by xtable 1.7-4 package
% Tue Aug 04 10:30:04 2015
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rlrr}
  \hline
 & Values & Frequencies & Percent \\ 
  \hline
1 & 1.513 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  2 & 1.615 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  3 & 1.835 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  4 & 1.935 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  5 & 2.14 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  6 & 2.2 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  7 & 2.32 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  8 & 2.465 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  9 & 2.62 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  10 & 2.77 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  11 & 2.78 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  12 & 2.875 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  13 & 3.15 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  14 & 3.17 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  15 & 3.19 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  16 & 3.215 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  17 & 3.435 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  18 & 3.44 &   3 & 0.09 \\ 
  19 & 3.46 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  20 & 3.52 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  21 & 3.57 &   2 & 0.06 \\ 
  22 & 3.73 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  23 & 3.78 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  24 & 3.84 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  25 & 3.845 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  26 & 4.07 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  27 & 5.25 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  28 & 5.345 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  29 & 5.424 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{wt} 
\label{wt}
\end{table}


  \clearpage
  \pagebreak


\section{\uppercase{qsec}}

Here is where the labels and other information will go: \\


  % latex table generated in R 3.2.1 by xtable 1.7-4 package
% Tue Aug 04 10:30:04 2015
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rlrr}
  \hline
 & Values & Frequencies & Percent \\ 
  \hline
1 & 14.5 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  2 & 14.6 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  3 & 15.41 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  4 & 15.5 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  5 & 15.84 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  6 & 16.46 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  7 & 16.7 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  8 & 16.87 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  9 & 16.9 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  10 & 17.02 &   2 & 0.06 \\ 
  11 & 17.05 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  12 & 17.3 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  13 & 17.4 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  14 & 17.42 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  15 & 17.6 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  16 & 17.82 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  17 & 17.98 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  18 & 18 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  19 & 18.3 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  20 & 18.52 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  21 & 18.6 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  22 & 18.61 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  23 & 18.9 &   2 & 0.06 \\ 
  24 & 19.44 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  25 & 19.47 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  26 & 19.9 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  27 & 20 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  28 & 20.01 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  29 & 20.22 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  30 & 22.9 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{qsec} 
\label{qsec}
\end{table}


  \clearpage
  \pagebreak


\section{\uppercase{vs}}

Here is where the labels and other information will go: \\


  % latex table generated in R 3.2.1 by xtable 1.7-4 package
% Tue Aug 04 10:30:04 2015
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rlrr}
  \hline
 & Values & Frequencies & Percent \\ 
  \hline
1 & 0 &  18 & 0.56 \\ 
  2 & 1 &  14 & 0.44 \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{vs} 
\label{vs}
\end{table}


  \clearpage
  \pagebreak


\section{\uppercase{am}}

Here is where the labels and other information will go: \\


  % latex table generated in R 3.2.1 by xtable 1.7-4 package
% Tue Aug 04 10:30:04 2015
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rlrr}
  \hline
 & Values & Frequencies & Percent \\ 
  \hline
1 & 0 &  19 & 0.59 \\ 
  2 & 1 &  13 & 0.41 \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{am} 
\label{am}
\end{table}


  \clearpage
  \pagebreak


\section{\uppercase{gear}}

Here is where the labels and other information will go: \\


  % latex table generated in R 3.2.1 by xtable 1.7-4 package
% Tue Aug 04 10:30:04 2015
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rlrr}
  \hline
 & Values & Frequencies & Percent \\ 
  \hline
1 & 3 &  15 & 0.47 \\ 
  2 & 4 &  12 & 0.38 \\ 
  3 & 5 &   5 & 0.16 \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{gear} 
\label{gear}
\end{table}


  \clearpage
  \pagebreak


\section{\uppercase{carb}}

Here is where the labels and other information will go: \\


  % latex table generated in R 3.2.1 by xtable 1.7-4 package
% Tue Aug 04 10:30:04 2015
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rlrr}
  \hline
 & Values & Frequencies & Percent \\ 
  \hline
1 & 1 &   7 & 0.22 \\ 
  2 & 2 &  10 & 0.31 \\ 
  3 & 3 &   3 & 0.09 \\ 
  4 & 4 &  10 & 0.31 \\ 
  5 & 6 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  6 & 8 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{carb} 
\label{carb}
\end{table}


  \clearpage
  \pagebreak


\section{\uppercase{Sepal.Length}}

Here is where the labels and other information will go: \\


  % latex table generated in R 3.2.1 by xtable 1.7-4 package
% Tue Aug 04 10:30:04 2015
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rlrr}
  \hline
 & Values & Frequencies & Percent \\ 
  \hline
1 & 4.3 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  2 & 4.4 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  3 & 4.6 &   3 & 0.09 \\ 
  4 & 4.7 &   2 & 0.06 \\ 
  5 & 4.8 &   4 & 0.12 \\ 
  6 & 4.9 &   2 & 0.06 \\ 
  7 & 5 &   4 & 0.12 \\ 
  8 & 5.1 &   5 & 0.16 \\ 
  9 & 5.2 &   2 & 0.06 \\ 
  10 & 5.4 &   5 & 0.16 \\ 
  11 & 5.7 &   2 & 0.06 \\ 
  12 & 5.8 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Sepal.Length} 
\label{Sepal.Length}
\end{table}


  \clearpage
  \pagebreak


\section{\uppercase{Sepal.Width}}

Here is where the labels and other information will go: \\


  % latex table generated in R 3.2.1 by xtable 1.7-4 package
% Tue Aug 04 10:30:05 2015
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rlrr}
  \hline
 & Values & Frequencies & Percent \\ 
  \hline
1 & 2.9 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  2 & 3 &   4 & 0.12 \\ 
  3 & 3.1 &   3 & 0.09 \\ 
  4 & 3.2 &   2 & 0.06 \\ 
  5 & 3.3 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  6 & 3.4 &   8 & 0.25 \\ 
  7 & 3.5 &   3 & 0.09 \\ 
  8 & 3.6 &   2 & 0.06 \\ 
  9 & 3.7 &   2 & 0.06 \\ 
  10 & 3.8 &   2 & 0.06 \\ 
  11 & 3.9 &   2 & 0.06 \\ 
  12 & 4 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  13 & 4.4 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Sepal.Width} 
\label{Sepal.Width}
\end{table}


  \clearpage
  \pagebreak


\section{\uppercase{Petal.Length}}

Here is where the labels and other information will go: \\


  % latex table generated in R 3.2.1 by xtable 1.7-4 package
% Tue Aug 04 10:30:05 2015
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rlrr}
  \hline
 & Values & Frequencies & Percent \\ 
  \hline
1 & 1 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  2 & 1.1 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  3 & 1.2 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  4 & 1.3 &   2 & 0.06 \\ 
  5 & 1.4 &   8 & 0.25 \\ 
  6 & 1.5 &   9 & 0.28 \\ 
  7 & 1.6 &   5 & 0.16 \\ 
  8 & 1.7 &   4 & 0.12 \\ 
  9 & 1.9 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Petal.Length} 
\label{Petal.Length}
\end{table}


  \clearpage
  \pagebreak


\section{\uppercase{Petal.Width}}

Here is where the labels and other information will go: \\


  % latex table generated in R 3.2.1 by xtable 1.7-4 package
% Tue Aug 04 10:30:05 2015
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rlrr}
  \hline
 & Values & Frequencies & Percent \\ 
  \hline
1 & 0.1 &   3 & 0.09 \\ 
  2 & 0.2 &  18 & 0.56 \\ 
  3 & 0.3 &   4 & 0.12 \\ 
  4 & 0.4 &   6 & 0.19 \\ 
  5 & 0.5 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Petal.Width} 
\label{Petal.Width}
\end{table}


  \clearpage
  \pagebreak


\section{\uppercase{Species}}

Here is where the labels and other information will go: \\


  % latex table generated in R 3.2.1 by xtable 1.7-4 package
% Tue Aug 04 10:30:05 2015
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rlrr}
  \hline
 & Values & Frequencies & Percent \\ 
  \hline
1 & setosa &  32 & 1.00 \\ 
  2 & versicolor &   0 & 0.00 \\ 
  3 & virginica &   0 & 0.00 \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Species} 
\label{Species}
\end{table}


  \clearpage
  \pagebreak


\section{\uppercase{Tree}}

Here is where the labels and other information will go: \\


  % latex table generated in R 3.2.1 by xtable 1.7-4 package
% Tue Aug 04 10:30:05 2015
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rlrr}
  \hline
 & Values & Frequencies & Percent \\ 
  \hline
1 & 3 &   7 & 0.22 \\ 
  2 & 1 &   7 & 0.22 \\ 
  3 & 5 &   4 & 0.12 \\ 
  4 & 2 &   7 & 0.22 \\ 
  5 & 4 &   7 & 0.22 \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Tree} 
\label{Tree}
\end{table}


  \clearpage
  \pagebreak


\section{\uppercase{age}}

Here is where the labels and other information will go: \\


  % latex table generated in R 3.2.1 by xtable 1.7-4 package
% Tue Aug 04 10:30:05 2015
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rlrr}
  \hline
 & Values & Frequencies & Percent \\ 
  \hline
1 & 118 &   5 & 0.16 \\ 
  2 & 484 &   5 & 0.16 \\ 
  3 & 664 &   5 & 0.16 \\ 
  4 & 1004 &   5 & 0.16 \\ 
  5 & 1231 &   4 & 0.12 \\ 
  6 & 1372 &   4 & 0.12 \\ 
  7 & 1582 &   4 & 0.12 \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{age} 
\label{age}
\end{table}


  \clearpage
  \pagebreak


\section{\uppercase{circumference}}

Here is where the labels and other information will go: \\


  % latex table generated in R 3.2.1 by xtable 1.7-4 package
% Tue Aug 04 10:30:05 2015
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rlrr}
  \hline
 & Values & Frequencies & Percent \\ 
  \hline
1 & 30 &   3 & 0.09 \\ 
  2 & 32 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  3 & 33 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  4 & 49 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  5 & 51 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  6 & 58 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  7 & 62 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  8 & 69 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  9 & 75 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  10 & 81 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  11 & 87 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  12 & 108 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  13 & 111 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  14 & 112 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  15 & 115 &   2 & 0.06 \\ 
  16 & 120 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  17 & 125 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  18 & 139 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  19 & 140 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  20 & 142 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  21 & 145 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  22 & 156 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  23 & 167 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  24 & 172 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  25 & 179 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  26 & 203 &   2 & 0.06 \\ 
  27 & 209 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  28 & 214 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{circumference} 
\label{circumference}
\end{table}


  \clearpage
  \pagebreak


\section{\uppercase{eruptions}}

Here is where the labels and other information will go: \\


  % latex table generated in R 3.2.1 by xtable 1.7-4 package
% Tue Aug 04 10:30:05 2015
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rlrr}
  \hline
 & Values & Frequencies & Percent \\ 
  \hline
1 & 1.6 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  2 & 1.75 &   3 & 0.09 \\ 
  3 & 1.8 &   2 & 0.06 \\ 
  4 & 1.833 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  5 & 1.95 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  6 & 1.967 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  7 & 2.167 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  8 & 2.283 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  9 & 2.883 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  10 & 3.067 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  11 & 3.333 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  12 & 3.45 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  13 & 3.6 &   3 & 0.09 \\ 
  14 & 3.85 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  15 & 3.917 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  16 & 4.083 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  17 & 4.2 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  18 & 4.25 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  19 & 4.3 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  20 & 4.35 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  21 & 4.433 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  22 & 4.467 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  23 & 4.533 &   2 & 0.06 \\ 
  24 & 4.7 &   2 & 0.06 \\ 
  25 & 4.8 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{eruptions} 
\label{eruptions}
\end{table}


  \clearpage
  \pagebreak


\section{\uppercase{waiting}}

Here is where the labels and other information will go: \\


  % latex table generated in R 3.2.1 by xtable 1.7-4 package
% Tue Aug 04 10:30:05 2015
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rlrr}
  \hline
 & Values & Frequencies & Percent \\ 
  \hline
1 & 47 &   2 & 0.06 \\ 
  2 & 51 &   2 & 0.06 \\ 
  3 & 52 &   2 & 0.06 \\ 
  4 & 54 &   2 & 0.06 \\ 
  5 & 55 &   2 & 0.06 \\ 
  6 & 62 &   2 & 0.06 \\ 
  7 & 69 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  8 & 73 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  9 & 74 &   2 & 0.06 \\ 
  10 & 76 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  11 & 77 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  12 & 78 &   3 & 0.09 \\ 
  13 & 79 &   3 & 0.09 \\ 
  14 & 83 &   2 & 0.06 \\ 
  15 & 84 &   2 & 0.06 \\ 
  16 & 85 &   3 & 0.09 \\ 
  17 & 88 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{waiting} 
\label{waiting}
\end{table}


  \clearpage
  \pagebreak


\section{\uppercase{extra}}

Here is where the labels and other information will go: \\


  % latex table generated in R 3.2.1 by xtable 1.7-4 package
% Tue Aug 04 10:30:05 2015
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rlrr}
  \hline
 & Values & Frequencies & Percent \\ 
  \hline
1 & -1.6 &   1 & 0.05 \\ 
  2 & -1.2 &   1 & 0.05 \\ 
  3 & -0.2 &   1 & 0.05 \\ 
  4 & -0.1 &   2 & 0.10 \\ 
  5 & 0 &   1 & 0.05 \\ 
  6 & 0.1 &   1 & 0.05 \\ 
  7 & 0.7 &   1 & 0.05 \\ 
  8 & 0.8 &   2 & 0.10 \\ 
  9 & 1.1 &   1 & 0.05 \\ 
  10 & 1.6 &   1 & 0.05 \\ 
  11 & 1.9 &   1 & 0.05 \\ 
  12 & 2 &   1 & 0.05 \\ 
  13 & 3.4 &   2 & 0.10 \\ 
  14 & 3.7 &   1 & 0.05 \\ 
  15 & 4.4 &   1 & 0.05 \\ 
  16 & 4.6 &   1 & 0.05 \\ 
  17 & 5.5 &   1 & 0.05 \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{extra} 
\label{extra}
\end{table}


  \clearpage
  \pagebreak


\section{\uppercase{group}}

Here is where the labels and other information will go: \\


  % latex table generated in R 3.2.1 by xtable 1.7-4 package
% Tue Aug 04 10:30:05 2015
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rlrr}
  \hline
 & Values & Frequencies & Percent \\ 
  \hline
1 & 1 &  10 & 0.50 \\ 
  2 & 2 &  10 & 0.50 \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{group} 
\label{group}
\end{table}


  \clearpage
  \pagebreak


\section{\uppercase{ID}}

Here is where the labels and other information will go: \\


  % latex table generated in R 3.2.1 by xtable 1.7-4 package
% Tue Aug 04 10:30:05 2015
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rlrr}
  \hline
 & Values & Frequencies & Percent \\ 
  \hline
1 & 1 &   2 & 0.10 \\ 
  2 & 2 &   2 & 0.10 \\ 
  3 & 3 &   2 & 0.10 \\ 
  4 & 4 &   2 & 0.10 \\ 
  5 & 5 &   2 & 0.10 \\ 
  6 & 6 &   2 & 0.10 \\ 
  7 & 7 &   2 & 0.10 \\ 
  8 & 8 &   2 & 0.10 \\ 
  9 & 9 &   2 & 0.10 \\ 
  10 & 10 &   2 & 0.10 \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{ID} 
\label{ID}
\end{table}


  \clearpage
  \pagebreak


\section{\uppercase{lat}}

Here is where the labels and other information will go: \\


  % latex table generated in R 3.2.1 by xtable 1.7-4 package
% Tue Aug 04 10:30:05 2015
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rlrr}
  \hline
 & Values & Frequencies & Percent \\ 
  \hline
1 & -30.2 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  2 & -28.74 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  3 & -28.11 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  4 & -26 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  5 & -23.5 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  6 & -23.3 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  7 & -22.63 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  8 & -22.58 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  9 & -21.44 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  10 & -21 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  11 & -20.97 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  12 & -20.84 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  13 & -20.7 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  14 & -20.62 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  15 & -20.42 &   2 & 0.06 \\ 
  16 & -19.84 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  17 & -19.68 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  18 & -19.66 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  19 & -18.54 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  20 & -17.97 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  21 & -17.94 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  22 & -17.83 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  23 & -17.47 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  24 & -16.46 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  25 & -16.32 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  26 & -15.94 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  27 & -14.72 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  28 & -13.64 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  29 & -12.26 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  30 & -11.7 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  31 & -10.98 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{lat} 
\label{lat}
\end{table}


  \clearpage
  \pagebreak


\section{\uppercase{long}}

Here is where the labels and other information will go: \\


  % latex table generated in R 3.2.1 by xtable 1.7-4 package
% Tue Aug 04 10:30:05 2015
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rlrr}
  \hline
 & Values & Frequencies & Percent \\ 
  \hline
1 & 165.96 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  2 & 166.1 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  3 & 166.32 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  4 & 166.74 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  5 & 167 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  6 & 167.51 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  7 & 169.92 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  8 & 179.24 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  9 & 179.59 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  10 & 179.78 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  11 & 180.16 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  12 & 180.28 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  13 & 180.31 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  14 & 180.69 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  15 & 180.79 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  16 & 181.03 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  17 & 181.16 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  18 & 181.47 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  19 & 181.49 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  20 & 181.5 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  21 & 181.62 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  22 & 181.66 &   2 & 0.06 \\ 
  23 & 181.74 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  24 & 181.93 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  25 & 181.96 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  26 & 182 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  27 & 182.11 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  28 & 182.37 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  29 & 184.1 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  30 & 184.31 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
  31 & 184.95 &   1 & 0.03 \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{long} 
\label{long}
\end{table}


  \clearpage

\end{document}
```

Comment: Mhhh, could you give us a full [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) that exhibits the problem. I wouldn't have thought that the text (table of contents) collides with the header, that strikes me as very odd - or did I not correctly understand your problem? Do you use some non-standard document class?

Comment: Also: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: I added an MWE that has the same problem.

Comment: Wow! That is certainly not what I would call minimal. Anyway, the option `nohead` to the [`geometry`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/geometry) package seems to do what it says on the tin, i.e. remove any space reserved for a header, which is very problematic if you actually do have a header. If you remove the option, the header will look just fine.

Comment: I had to use a long example because I needed a table of contents that was over a page for the exaple

Comment: @moewe Would you like to turn your comment into a proper answer?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have loaded the `geometry` package with the `nohead` option. Unsurprisingly, this option makes the space normally reserved for headers available for the text.
Since you still set a header you see a clash.

The solution is to remove the `nohead` option to give the header the space it needs.